# How to always display the alt attribute of an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to always display the alt attribute of an anchor tag in HTML?

Here is a situation where I have multiple repeating grids and I want to identify with date.
So i want to show the title always, how can I achieve this?

```
<a href="#" title="created at 12 october">see details</a>
<a href="#" title="created at 13 october">see details</a>
<a href="#" title="created at 14 october">see details</a>
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wub5y96d/1/

Comment: Putting text in anchor will be better

Comment: @Satpal,how that can be done

Comment: @Satpal, in href i want to include some page reference

Comment: `<a href="#" title="created at 14 october">created at 14 october, see details</a>`

Comment: or: `<span>Created at 14 october</span><a href="#" title="created at 14 october">see details</a>`

Comment: This what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/wub5y96d/5/

Comment: I think if you put it on anchor. You must remove the title attr. It is redundant.

Comment: @connexo that's a really, really neat piece of code. Impressive

Comment: i got my answer if @Roberrrt post it as a answer i will mark as answer

Comment: You can Put text in anchor or use jquery UI Tooltip

Comment: My answer isn't incorrect. It's an alternative approach. Which does give OP what he requires in the easiest way possible. I hands down do agree connexo's way is the most elegant + best answer.

Comment: @connexo is not correct Roberrrt  is :)

Comment: Can we stop saying who is correct and who isn't? Make your point on the individual post and move on please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can output the content of an element's attribute using `content: attr(attribute);` on either of the pseudo elements `::after` or `::before`, like this:

```
a[title]::after {
  content: ' ('attr(title)')';
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wub5y96d/5/)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I would like to suggest using `:before` in this case, since `:before` suits the 'Created at 14 october - see more' better.

Comment: I'd actually decide which one to use based on the position OP wants to render the attribute content. Should he wish your suggestion, he should use `::before`, should he wish for something like "see details (created on October 3rd)", `::after`'d be the natural solution.

Comment: @Roberrrt, i was about to accept your answer but you have deleted, now i have good choice i,e connexo.

Comment: Would be a bad thing if i'd undelete it with a much better alternative solution ready ;).

Answer (score 1):

try this simple loop

```
$('a').each(function(){
 var text = $(this).text();
 var title = $(this).attr('title');
 $(this).text(text+'-'+title);
});
```

Comment: Why use Javascript (or even jQuery) here?

Comment: because he can :)

Comment: That's not an argument.

Comment: if i remember correctly search engines don't have access to pseudo elements

Comment: But search engine will have access to the title of the anchor which is what is needed.

Comment: in my opinion this is better for SEO

Comment: You think Javascript is better for SEO?

Comment: @DavidG i think that having all the text in the link if better for seo

Comment: A search engine will not run Javascript so your code will have zero effect on SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Why do people keep using Fiddle's.  When Snippets will work just as fine.. :)

You can run them directly inside SO, how cool is that.   Oh, well maybe it's just me..

```css
a::after {
  position: absolute;  
  top: 16px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  color: silver;
  content: attr(data-created);
  font-size: smaller;
}
a {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <a href="#" data-created="created at 12 october">see details</a>
</div>
<div>
   <a href="#" data-created="created at 15 october">see details</a>
</div>
```